# How to add some buttons to selected ListBox item via style?

Tags: delphi, listbox, firemonkey, listboxitem

Is there a way to add some buttons to the selected ListBoxItem by adding these buttons to a style which is being used for the selected item?

I didn't yet find a suitable style FMX uses to display the selected item.

My goal is to have some buttons on the selected item with context based functionality. While I can do this by reparenting a TButton created in code in the OnPaint event of the ListBox, this works for Android but not for Win32 as it is being overpainted by the selection.

Other solutions like doing this in OnItemClick or OnClick are sluggish or only work properly on Win32 but not on Android and would need to be put into a timer fired on click.

Comment: You have to set the `lbOwnerDrawFixed` value to the `TListBox.Style` property. Draw the images to the canvas and handle mouse events in the right region to call the "onButtonClick" handlers.

Comment: It seems you are talking about VCL TListBox. Sorry, but I'm not talking about VCL TListBox but FMX TListBox. I didn't find any .Style property for FMX TListBox.

Comment: Sorry I have forgotten it. I never do anything by FMX.

Comment: A non style based solution is over there: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52328368/button-placed-on-selected-tlistitem-in-most-cases-doesnt-receive-click?noredirect=1#comment91612594_52328368](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52328368/button-placed-on-selected-tlistitem-in-most-cases-doesnt-receive-click?noredirect=1#comment91612594_52328368)