# Button placed on selected TListItem in most cases doesn't receive click

Tags: delphi, listbox, firemonkey

I have a Firemonkey TListBox in an Android app and in OnPaint I place 3 buttons on the selected TListBoxItem. They are being displayed and all have a OnClick event assigned. But when clicking them this event usually does not fire. Only seldom I get the button clicked.

I guess the TListBox already received the click and declared it as handled.
Is there any way otherwise? Can I register a tap in the form itsself and determine from the position of the tap which of the buttons must have been pressed? How would that work?

Here's the code of the current solution, the TListBox is client aligned to the form and the buttons in the TLayout are right aligned.

```
unit MainForm;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, 
  System.Variants, FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, 
  FMX.Dialogs, FMX.Layouts, FMX.ListBox, FMX.Controls.Presentation, 
  FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.Objects;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    lb_Files: TListBox;
    Layout1: TLayout;
    Image1: TImage;
    Image2: TImage;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    Rectangle1: TRectangle;
    Rectangle2: TRectangle;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure lb_FilesPaint(Sender: TObject; Canvas: TCanvas;
      const ARect: TRectF);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
  public
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses
  System.UIConsts;

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  lb_Files.ListItems[lb_Files.ItemIndex].Text := 'Info';
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  lb_Files.ListItems[lb_Files.ItemIndex].Text := 'Test';
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i : Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to 30 do
    lb_Files.Items.Add('File' + i.ToString +'.dat');
end;

procedure TForm1.lb_FilesPaint(Sender: TObject; Canvas: TCanvas;
  const ARect: TRectF);
begin
  if lb_Files.ItemIndex > -1 then
  begin
    Layout1.Parent  := lb_Files.ListItems[lb_Files.ItemIndex];
    Layout1.Align   := TAlignLayout.Right;
    Layout1.Visible := true;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Here is the FMX content's now:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 480
  ClientWidth = 640
  StyleBook = StyleBook1
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  DesignerMasterStyle = 3
  object lb_Files: TListBox
    Align = Client
    Enabled = False
    Size.Width = 640.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 480.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    StyleLookup = 'listboxstyle'
    TabOrder = 0
    OnPaint = lb_FilesPaint
    DisableFocusEffect = True
    DefaultItemStyles.ItemStyle = 'listboxitemstyle'
    DefaultItemStyles.GroupHeaderStyle = ''
    DefaultItemStyles.GroupFooterStyle = ''
    Viewport.Width = 640.000000000000000000
    Viewport.Height = 480.000000000000000000
    object Layout1: TLayout
      Position.X = 384.000000000000000000
      Position.Y = 192.000000000000000000
      Size.Width = 153.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 50.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      TabOrder = 0
      object Rectangle1: TRectangle
        Align = Right
        Fill.Color = claBlue
        HitTest = False
        Position.X = 53.000000000000000000
        Size.Width = 50.000000000000000000
        Size.Height = 50.000000000000000000
        Size.PlatformDefault = False
        Stroke.Kind = None
        OnClick = Button1Click
        object Button1: TButton
          Align = Client
          Size.Width = 50.000000000000000000
          Size.Height = 50.000000000000000000
          Size.PlatformDefault = False
          StyleLookup = 'buttonstyle'
          TabOrder = 0
          TintColor = claBlue
          OnClick = Button1Click
        end
      end
      object Rectangle2: TRectangle
        Align = Right
        Fill.Color = claGreen
        HitTest = False
        Position.X = 103.000000000000000000
        Size.Width = 50.000000000000000000
        Size.Height = 50.000000000000000000
        Size.PlatformDefault = False
        Stroke.Kind = None
        OnClick = Button2Click
        object Button2: TButton
          Align = Client
          Size.Width = 50.000000000000000000
          Size.Height = 50.000000000000000000
          Size.PlatformDefault = False
          StyleLookup = 'buttonstyle'
          TabOrder = 0
          TintColor = claGreen
          OnClick = Button2Click
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Please Markus, add a [mcve] to your question. Also explain why you change the structure of your form in the **OnPaint event**. That sounds totally wrong.

Comment: If you just draw the buttons on the canvas (as I suggested you in another question), then it is just an image of the buttons. in this case handle the onclick events by the list box. if the click position is inside in the boundrect of the button, just call its `onclick` event handler by program. (I suggested it as well in that answer)

Comment: I change the structure in OnPains because this displays the buttons immediately when I click on an item. Other methods like reparenting them in OnClick/OnItem click all have a highly visible time lag.

My original question ist how to add buttons to a selected TListBoxItem and only the selected one which can be cliekd on by the user on ANdroid. On WIn32 my current solution fails anyway as the selection seems to be painted over the buttons so they're not visible.

My 1st idea was to add them to a style element which is used for displaying a selected ListBox item, but I didn't succeed.

Comment: Link to my first idea: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52311599/how-to-add-some-buttons-to-selected-listbox-item-via-style?noredirect=1#comment91581759_52311599](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52311599/how-to-add-some-buttons-to-selected-listbox-item-via-style?noredirect=1#comment91581759_52311599)

Comment: Thanks for the code, but the .fmx is missing, or otherwise what the relation between (all) the components are. Are the images and rectangles important to demonstrate the problem? What is `ItemHeight` in listbox? What style are you using?

Comment: Ok, the images and rectangles are not really needed (the rectangles have HitTest = false anyway and are just needed to work around some FMX issue that right alinged TButtons always have a border around them even if I don't specify any margins or paddings neither on the TButtons nor on the TLayout which contains them.

As for the FMX: just create a blank multi device project, add a TListBox named lb_files which is client aligned, a TLayout and two right aligned buttons to that TLayout. If you like set stylelookup to buttonstyle and apply a tintcolor. ItemHeight is left untouched for now.

Comment: I tested and saw ghost buttons (instead of two buttons, there are four, of which only two ofcourse works) after changing selected item. As I thought `OnPaint` is the wrong event. Use `OnChange()` (`lb_filesChange()`) instead. Works exactly every time.

Comment: Will try your suggestion on Monday, thanks for testing. Your test result differs from mine. You might have seen I added the FMX contents now. And the problem I have is that the way it is implemented clicking on the buttons mostly doesn't work, which I fear will not be different when being done via OnChanged. Additionally OnChanged might add the unwanted time gap between selecting the item and placing the buttons, but I'll test it, be sure!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion with the OnCHange event! This really seems to work on a first test!